# Why react hooks cleanup function is executed when reopening a closed tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks, safari

I have a problem when I close a tab and then I undo that action. It basically executes all the cleanup functions in the component, aborting the new fetches that are needed to load the component (old cleanup functions are aborting new fetches).
For Chrome and Firefox, it works fine. For what I have tested, it happens only on Safari.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    fetch(`${URL}${API.mediaDetails}`
    + `?id=${encodeURIComponent(props.match.params.id)}`
    + `&type=${encodeURIComponent(props.match.params.type)}`
    + `&lang=${encodeURIComponent(props.match.params.locale?.slice(0, 2))}`, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
        timeout: DOWNLOAD_HUB_REQ_TIMEOUT
    }).then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => {
        res.type = props.match.params.type;
        return setDetails(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        setDetails(null);
        setError(err);
    });

    return () => abortController.abort();
}, [props.match.params]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanup function (to abort the request) will be run whenever the component is removed from the DOM.  When you close the tab, that component (and in fact, *all* of the components on the page) will be removed, which means all their cleanup functions will be run.

This is normally what you want.  If you go to `/foo/1`, and you start fetching data for foo #1 ... but then you change pages to `/foo/2` ... you *want* to abort the fetch for foo #1!  You don't need it anymore, so why have it slow down the request for foo #2?

However, if you for some reason don't want this behavior, you could always set some sort of flag (eg. `dontCleanup`) before the user leaves, and then check for that flag in your cleanup function.

**NOTE:** Individual browsers (eg. Safari) may have bugs that violate this behavior.  Upgrading to the latest browser version should resolve it.

Comment: But having that flag would be exactly like not writing the cleanup function. How that would fix the problem? I mean, to do cleanup when I change pages to `/foo/2`, but to avoid it when closing the tab. The target behaviour would be to perform the fetch again when the close tab action is undone, so the cleanup function does not affect this new fetch, but it does.

Comment: I don't understand: why don't you want it to abort when you close the tab?  Or, if you're talking about when you re-open the tab, why would it matter whether some fetches (made before the tab was closed) are aborted?

Comment: No, I want to abort everything when the tab is closed. The problem is it is aborting the new fetches that are done when the app is reopened. To schematise a bit the problematic current behaviour: `/foo/1` is opened, fetches are initiated, tab is closed, tab is reopened, new fetches are initiated, new and old fetches are aborted.

Comment: Something isn't adding up here.  Each abort controller can only abort the fetches that its signal was passed to.  If you are creating a new `AbortController` inside your `useEffect` (as you showed in your code), a new one should be created each time `useEffect` is run.  It should be impossible for an old cleanup function to abort a new `fetch`, because the new `fetch` should use a different controller.

Comment: I have been doing more tests and I have found it happens only on Safari. For chrome and firefox it works as intended. But yeah, I have tracked it and, without any doubt, the old cleanup function is aborting the new fetches...

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue in older Safari versions: https://github.com/mo/abortcontroller-polyfill/issues/23  Perhaps upgrading your browser might fix it (although obviously not for anyone else using an old Safari).  Alternatively you could use a polyfil (like the one I linked) to do Apple's job for them.

Comment: Thanks. I will test that polyfil. I have the latest version, so there's nothing to do.